# $_GET, Ampersand is interrupting

Tags: php, get

Trying to use a $_GET['url'] variable to grab data from a URL:

http://mysite.com/?url=**http://this.is/?q=an&?example=url**

What I want above is bolded, but sadly the $_GET['url'] will only get "http:// this.is/?q=an" because the & makes it interpret it as the beginning of a new variable within the URL.

Is there a way to ignore the ampersands so my script can get the entire URL I need it to? The URL that is appended to ?url= is not within my limits to control so most work but some do contain the dreaded &. After reading questions on Stack Overflow I'm not holding out much hope :(

Comment: `URL Encode` your `GET` string before you submit the page. Then `URL Decode` the `$_GET` before manipulating it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have absolutely no control over the arguments placed on the query string (for whatever reason), you can also do this by manually parsing the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` varible, e.g.

```
$page = str_replace("url=", "", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Of course, if possible, you should encode it using the answers posted by everyone else.

Comment: +1 for actually taking note of the "the URL is not within my limits to control" and providing the OP with an alternate way of getting the entire URL.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you! Appreciate you giving me an answer w/o urlencode() which I can't use.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

```
$get_url = urlencode('http://this.is/?q=an&?example=url');
$url = 'http://mysite.com/?url=' . $get_url;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't control the query string, you could use

```
$query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$pos = strpos($query, "url=");
if ($pos !== false) {
    $url = substr($query, $pos + 4);
}
```

This code returns everthing after `url=`

If you have the possibility,you should encode the url with `urlencode` to create a clean url.
If you don't do this, you get eventually an server error, with strange urls and you can't pass more than one url(because everything after the url= is interpreted as url)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tested code:

```
if (!empty($_GET['url'])) {
    echo $_GET['url'].'<br />';
}
$url = urlencode('http://this.is/?q=an&?example=url');
echo '<a href="http://mysite.com/?url='.$url.'">LINK</a>';
```

Hope it will help you.